# Refactoring switch statement

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have this switch statement

```
string status = "1";
switch (status)
{
    case "1":
        Button1.Visible = true;
        Button2.Visible = true;
        Button3.Visible = true;
        Button4.Visible = true;
        Button5.Visible = true;
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        break;
    case "2":
        Button1.Visible = true;
        Button2.Visible = true;
        Button3.Visible = true;
        Button4.Visible = true;
        Button5.Visible = true;
        Panel2.Visible = true;
        break;
}
```

and there is some code redundancy. In both cases `Button1` - `5` are shown and the `Panel` referring to the `status` value.

Is there a way to make the code shorter?

My approach with less redundancy but more lines - is there another obvious way I haven't thought of?

```
string status = "1";
switch (status)
{
    case "1":
    case "2":
        Button1.Visible = true;
        Button2.Visible = true;
        Button3.Visible = true;
        Button4.Visible = true;
        Button5.Visible = true;
        break;
}
switch (status)
{
    case "1":
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        break;
    case "2":
        Panel2.Visible = true;
        break;
}
```

Comment: Sure: by extracting a method that you call in both cases.

Comment: Pick better names for your controls. And also, if you want to *index into* your set of panels, why not put them in a List?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this is just sample code to clarify my problem

Comment: Is that intentional, that you do _not_ set any of the Panels _invisible_ in any cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a method for button visibility:

```
private void SetButtonVisibility(bool show)
{
    Button1.Visible = show;
    Button2.Visible = show;
    Button3.Visible = show;
    Button4.Visible = show;
    Button5.Visible = show;
}
```

Then call this method in your `switch` statement:

```
switch (status)
{
    case "1":
        SetButtonVisibility(true);
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        break;
    case "2":
        SetButtonVisibility(true);
        Panel2.Visible = true;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about making a function that switch all needed things? If you add something then you will only edit that function keeping your switch clean:

```
string status = "1";
switch (status)
{
    case "1":
        enableSomething(true);
        break;
    case "2":
        enableSomething(false);
        break;
}
```

And then:

```
enableSomething(bool switcher) {
    switcher ? Panel2.Visible = true : Panel1.Visible = true;
    Button1.Visible = true;
    Button2.Visible = true;
    Button3.Visible = true;
    Button4.Visible = true;
    Button5.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the buttons to a list and use `ForEach` to set property

```
var listButton = new List<Button> {button1, button2, ...}

switch (status)
{
    case "1":
       listButton.ForEach(b => b.Visible = true);
       Panel1.Visible = true;
       break;
    case "2":
       listButton.ForEach(b => b.Visible = true);
       Panel2.Visible = true;
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One interesting approach you might consider taking is to go declarative.

Let's create a class, we'll call it `State`:

```
public class State {
    public string Status {get; set;}
}
```

The idea being, that you put anything in this class that make affect UI state. At the moment, we just have the `Status` property.

Then, you create some "behaviour" methods (these could just be lambdas; All we want/need is that they're generally reusable and can satisfy `Action<State,Control>`):

```
private void VisibleOn1Or2(State state, Control control)
{
   control.Visible = (state.Status == "1" || state.Status == "2");
}
private void VisibleOn1(State state, Control control)
{
   control.Visible = (state.Status == "1");
}
//Etc
```

Then, create a `Dictionary<Control,List<Action<State,Control>>>` collection (I'll call it `uiUpdates` below), and add all of the behaviours that you want. Note that this design allows you to have multiple cracks at each control - maybe you want to affect `Font` based on `State` as well as `Visible` and you can use two small methods to do this if desired rather than a single method that deals with both.

This `Dictionary` should be populated straight after `InitializeControls` has finished working.

Note now you can have a single method:

```
private void AfterStateUpdated(State newState)
{
   foreach(var kvp in uiUpdates)
   {
      var c = kvp.Key;
      foreach(var update in kvp.Value)
      {
         update(newState,c);
      }
   }
}
```

And you call that whenever your state changes. Now you don't have to have a gloryhole method than knows exactly how to update all UI state based on all possible `State` values.

---

(In the above, I assume there's a single `State` instance in a form field as well, but I still prefer to pass the `State` explicitly to the `Action` methods rather than having them pick it up from the `Form`. This enhances opportunities for reuse if you want to have a central set of methods used by multiple forms (assuming that the `State` *definition* is also suitable for such sharing))

Answer (score -1):

You can create new method to handle visibility status for the buttons as below:

```
    private void ChangeButtonVisibility(bool Status)
    {
        Button1.Visible = Status;
        Button2.Visible = Status;
        Button3.Visible = Status;
        Button4.Visible = Status;
        Button5.Visible = Status;
        Panel1.Visible = Status;
    }
```

Then from switch statement just call the method with proper value as below:

```
        switch (status)
        {
            case "1":
                ChangeButtonVisibility(true);
                break;
            case "2":
                ChangeButtonVisibility(false);
                break;
        }
```

Comment: In the original code example, Panel 1 changes with case 1 and Panel 2 changes with case 2, so you'll need to remove the `Panel1.Visible` from your `ChangeButtonVisibility` method and add it as a second line in the `case`.

Comment: Yes, I was just explaining the idea it self not providing a full solution. Thanks for your tip.